# Can questions about the IELTS exam be asked here?

Tags: support, scope

I am wondering if I can possible ask questions regarding IELTS/TOEFL exam here in ELL. Why I am asking is because in case I ask, someone can vote down my question and say this is not the right place to ask them. I can see there is no tag named [ielts](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ielts). So please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I misunderstood the question; the below answer was written based on the understanding that the question meant "I saw an English question on this exam that I didn't understand. Can I ask a question here about why [x] answer is the right one?" For questions requiring the exam administration itself, I highly endorse [Martha's answer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/687/289).

---

Sure you can! Just make sure to follow the usual rules for asking any question, which include:

1. If possible, show your research. Please try and find an answer to your question before asking it here, and tell us what you found.
2. Tell us what you think is wrong about the sentence, or why you're confused, or what you think it should be; whatever applies. It helps us to give you great answers if you share your thought process with us! If we know where you're confused, it's easier to help.

So go ahead and ask your question! Just share as much with us as possible, so the question and answers are the best they can possibly be :)

Comment: This user asked over on ELU first (I directed him here), and his sample question was "can IELTS possible give you a certificate with the score of 4 or below, because I've never hear someone getting it. One of my acquaintance's exam is imminent, but I am not sure if she takes 5 or more".

Comment: It's not completely certain what OP is actually asking, but on the basis of what I've seen so far, my guess is he means *"Can I ask questions **about** IELTS/TOEFL [exams] here?"* So I'm afraid I must downvote the question (because I think such questions are Off Topic) and this answer (because the first sentence misleadingly implies they're okay).

Comment: I agree with you, @FumbleFingers. I should have named the title as you stated. However, I also think that the users of this site might ask a kind of language question and the acceptance or possible synonyms or more appropriate usage of a word or phrase. And maybe they ask some techniques when it comes to writing style.

Comment: An example is, `can I use following phrase in my IELTS essay: for a start. According to one book, this is said to be an idiom. As far as I am concerned, it's not acceptable making use of idioms when writing an essay`. I don't think this is more about the language itself though, but there could be other more appropriate ones. For this reason, I request that you create a new `tag` on this, and let users to feel welcome to this site in terms of those exam-based language problems.

Comment: @boburShox: I assume by *it's not acceptable making use of idioms when writing an essay* you mean you know (or think) that's an IELTS/TOEFL requirement. But idiomatic usages are very common in natural English (both speech and writing, formal and informal). I suppose *for a start* could be called idiomatic, but the reason you should avoid it in "formal writing" is because it's an *informal (primarily **spoken**)* form, not because it's an "idiom".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for pointing this out; I've updated the answer. I think Martha's got it covered.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean asking questions about the IELTS exam itself, i.e. questions about what score you need to get for [x], or how to go about scheduling a test, or other administrative details, then I'm afraid there is no Stack Exchange site where the question would be on-topic. If you have the necessary reputation, you can try asking in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7227/english-language-learners), but your best bet is to contact the [IELTS](http://www.ielts.org/) organization directly.