# Are questions about English language certifications on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Is it an appropriate place to ask questions about language certifications like IELTS, CAE and others? E.g. questions about exam format, learning materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been some past discussions here on Meta. To list a few that I've found:

[Where can I ask questions about TOEFL and GRE?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2385/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-toefl-and-gre)

[Can questions about the IELTS exam be asked here?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/685/can-questions-about-the-ielts-exam-be-asked-here)

In sum, if your question is "What books should I use to better prepare for the exam?" then it is unfortunately off-topic on ELL. You can try asking in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow) but I doubt many people active in chat now are familiar with IELTS or CAE (I don't know what CAE is). Your best bet is probably their official websites. Or you can see if there are dedicated discussion forums out there that might be helpful to you.

If you have a question from the exam that is about the English language, fire away. Be sure to include the [exam-questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exam-questions) tag.

We do have a resource list where you might be able to find useful stuff.

[Resources for learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english)

Comment: I think CAE is Certificate in Advanced English.

Answer (score 1):

For a complete review of English exams organised by Cambridge, visit their [website](https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/) and click on the tab, **Exams and Tests**. This will open a menu with a list of all their exams.

For [**IELTS**](https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/exams-and-tests/ielts/), the site will explain the following:

- Test format
- Preparation
- Test dates
- Results
- Total qualification time

Meanwhile, it's important to know that Cambridge decided to revamp a few of their exam formats in January 2020, so avoid  English exam websites that are not up-to-date with the most recent developments.

The CAE has been renamed **[C1 Advanced](https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/exams-and-tests/advanced/)**. A candidate can find information about the following aspects

- Exam format   (You can also download the four sample examination papers)
- Preparation
- Exam dates
- Results
- Testimonials

How do I know about this? I am a qualified Cambridge Speaking examiner, so it's my job to know :)